# Batch script can't be launch except when restarting computer

Tags: python, batch-file

I have a recent issue on my computer.

From a moment, the batch scripts can't be launch anymore. Indeed when i double click on one of them nothing happens.
If i look at the Task manager I can see multiples cmd.exe running. If i delete all of them I still cannot open any cmd.exe.

I discovered that this issue happens after a batch scripts stops in the middle for no reason.

The only way to "repair" this problem is by restarting my computer. But the issue comes again and again...

Same issue happens with python scripts.

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: If you close all instances of cmd.exe in the Task Manager, does the problem persist?

Comment: Yes I tried this, the problem is still here

Comment: Can you start a new cmd.exe?

Comment: No, neither in admin mode nor in normal mode. I only have 204K cmd.exe in Task Manager

Comment: It's not a memory problem because I am around 4Go right now and I have 8Go

Comment: It will help if show the content of the bat file.

Comment: I have all my batch file that does not work but here is one of them :

`if exist HL_Merge_All_signed.xml del HL_Merge_All_signed.xml
rename "HL_Merge_All.xml" "HL_Merge_All_signed.xml"
exit`

Comment: Can you manually open C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe?

Comment: what do you mean by "manually open" ?

Comment: I mean open Explorer, navigate to C:\Windows\system32, and double-click on cmd.exe instead of however you're normally opening it. I figured you were double-clicking a shortcut or a link on the Start Menu or something.

Comment: Ah ok, same problem then

Comment: Hello, another remark i just found. This issue is coming when i have a cmd.exe which stops in the middle of its script. To unblock it I quit the window. Then the cmd.exe is no longer available